# Will a python socket timeout?

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I am trying to create a client server program in python and im wondering once the connection is made will it ever timeout unless I close the connection somehow?

if so is there a way of keeping the connection open? or a flag to keep the connection always open??

Basically I want the client to connect and stay connected indefinitely.

Comment: If you have the server part under control, consider using zmq as method for communication, it will provide a lot of simply working functionality as automatic reconnection etc.

Comment: The network is not reliable! Sockets *will die* for a number of reasons, do not design your program as if they wouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will ensure that my client will check for disconnects and reconnect if needed to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[socket.settimeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout)

From the docs:

***socket.settimeout(value)***
Set a timeout on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative float expressing seconds, or None. If a float is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. Setting a timeout of None disables timeouts on socket operations. s.settimeout(0.0) is equivalent to s.setblocking(0); s.settimeout(None) is equivalent to s.setblocking(1).

So, if you don't call settimeout, your connection will remain open until you or the other host close it. And, of course, nothing goes wrong like a intermediary host goes down of any other failure.
Then, you have to monitor your connection and reopen if down.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the connection open with the TCP KEEPALIVE option. See the (linux howto)[[http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#overview]](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/#overview%5d). I'm not sure of the details in Windows. Its complicated enough that reading the docs is better than an example here. Keepalive is disabled by default on linux kernels which gives you a good idea how popular it is (read: not very). As others have suggested, gracefully handling disconnection or even adding a ping packet to your protocol are other options.